# Shared / Common templates using RazorEngine library

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor

I am using the RazorEngine library to create templates for my PDF generation in my application. RazorEngine allows me to utilize Razor outside of the normal asp.net web context.

How do I create shared / common .cshtml files that I can reuse? For example a **Footer** template. Since my Footer is going to look the same for most of my PDFs I would like to have a common footer template that I can call.

How do I do this using RazorEngine?

Answer (score 1):

Make a "footer.cshtml" as a partial view. Then call it with `@Html.RenderPartial("footer").`